# Appending an ending tag to incomplete input elements in HTML

Tags: html, regex, vb.net, input, append

I have code such as:

```
<form>
    <input name="whatever">
    <input name="whatever2">
</form>
```

And for the XML parser in Visual Basic .NET to be able to parse this, I need to close each input tag. Like so:

```
<input></input>
```

How would I append this to each input in the HTML string I have? By using Regex?

```
Dim Method As New Regex("<input.*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
For each Item as String in Method.Results("<form><input><input></form>")
    'Somehow append </input>
Next
```

Comment: input tags are self closing, you need to close them like `<input />` that

Comment: Either way, I need a way to append it to each one.

Comment: @RUJordan Depends on the doctype :)

Comment: Just use an HTML parser instead of an XML parser; there are plenty of other things that won’t work, should they be possible in your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a very simple regex to fix the inputs.  And there are several replacement patterns you can use depending on how you want the format of the elements to be.

### Sample Code

```
Function FixInputElement(htmlMarkup As String)
    Return Regex.Replace(htmlMarkup, "(<input[^>]*)(>)", "$1/$2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
End Function
```

### Replacement Patterns

```
Replacement     Input              Output
$1/$2           <input id="in1">   <input id="in1"/>
$1 /$2          <input id="in2">   <input id="in2" />
$1/$2</input>   <input id="in3">   <input id="in3"></input>
```

### Adding Negative Lookbehind

In case there is a chance that some inputs are correctly closed you can add a negative lookbehind

```
(<input[^>]*)((?<!/)>)
```

### Output with Negated Lookbehind

```
Input                         Output
<input id="in1">              <input id="in1" />
<input id="in2">              <input id="in2" />
<input id="in3-dontfix" />    <input id="in3-dontfix" />
```